# Calculate distance from a point to the border of polygon (US state)

Tags: distance

I have a point, and I want to know if it is nearer than 100 miles from some US State border (California for example).

I assume that I would need to use this: US Regions State Boundaries. But if I compare my point with the points of a state polygon, I will only get a result if my point is near some of the polygon's points and not the border itself.

If this is possible, is possible to do something similar with ZIP Codes? For example: I want to get 33139, and every location on my array of locations that is near it.

Comment: Is this 100 miles on a road, or "as the crow flies" ?  Is this only 1 state you are dealing with?  If you simply want to know if the point is within 100 miles of the state border, why dont you create a 100 mile buffer around the state and see if the point falls within it (either visually or through a spatial join)  Also please explain the last sentence better, I can't figure out what you are trying to say or do.

Comment: What software do you have access to? You could do a buffer, but I don't think that's the fastest or most generic way to do this.

Comment: If you are looking to check the distance from borders just use a line shapefile (can convert the state polygons to lines to get the borders) and a spatial query (can just search by location).